# ASP.NET MVC 3 Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new to MVC. I am coming from web forms.

I have a simple search page. The user has option of  searching contacts by state. I have a multi select box where they can select multiple states and click search contacts.

The result contacts will be displayed in a grid. The grid has options of edit,details and delete.

When they click delete it goes to a different page and asks for confirmation. Once they click delete and its done succesfully i am redirecting to the search page. But i want to redirect them to the same list they have earlier.

How i can acheive this with MVC ??

I am storing the selected state ids in an integer array in the view model.

Comment: So what are your current ideas? What have you tried so far? What difficulties did you encounter? Some code you are willing to share with us?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a modal popup and then doing an Ajax request and bind the results to a Partial view on the page.

Ie. `$('#partialDiv').load( your controller call here )`

Might make for a better experience...

Comment: I dont want to use ajax or javascript with this site.

Comment: No worries, when you navigate back to the search page, you should re-load the list (after your controller does the delete) and the grid should be refreshed.

Comment: For reloading the list i should know the states they have selected earlier .. How would i know them .. i should either use sessions or something else. i am struck there .. :(

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean.  You could store in a hidden field and retrieve on the server, or yes, you could do Session variable.  Hidden field might be the way to go, reduces complexity and memory. :)

Comment: Ok .. I am just looking to see if there is a better way of achieving this in asp.net mvc ... for now i may be using session variable ..